# Resizing window issues

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am stuck with one of my school project as I am having trouble solving it.
Whenever I resize my window the menus get collapsed. I am sharing screenshot and my script.

**This is during maximize window view:**

[image]

**This happen when I minimize all my menu options goes down when I resize window:**

[image]

I am sharing with my script of this page, but it is happening on all the pages. Please check the script below:

```css
#topnav {
    height:50px;
  width:100%;
       position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color:black;
     font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
     overflow: hidden;
    
   
}
#menu1 {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color:Highlight;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    #menu1 a {
        color: Highlight;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


#menu2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    display: block;
    float:right;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    
}


#menu2 a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    #menu2 a:hover {
        color: Highlight;
    }
.main {
    min-height: 850px;
    height:auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
.clear {
    height: 100px;
}

.footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    bottom: -1px !important;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -1;
    position:page;
}
    .footer a {
        color: cornflowerblue;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #wrapper{
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<body style="height: 631px">
    
   
       <div id="wrapper">
           
                    <div id="topnav" >
                        <span id="menu1">
                            <a href="Login.aspx" runat ="server">APPLY FOR AUDIENCE</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="~/Groups.aspx" runat="server">APPLY FOR GROUPS</a>
                        </span>
                        <span id="menu2">
                            <a href="Home.aspx" runat="server">HOME</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="~/About Us.aspx" runat="server">ABOUT US</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="~/Contact.aspx" runat="server">CONTACT</a></span>
                    </div>
              
       
    
       
 <div class="main">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
    <div class="clear">
</div>
    <br /><br />
      <div class = "footer">
        <a href="Privacy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a> <a href="Terms.aspx">Terms of Use</a> <br />
                Copyright @ 2017 All Rights Reserved.  

                
    </div >

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the topnav height to `auto` or whatever suits you. Setting it at 50px is the issue.

```
#topnav {
    height:auto;
  width:100%;
       position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 14pt;
    background-color:black;
     font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
     overflow: hidden;


}
```

Comment: This code worked but still have issues when I resize the window the text doesn't stay over there but move while resizing. What I am looking for is that it should move to a certain extent while resizing but later it should remain fix to the certain position and one can scroll to use those menu buttons.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understood what you meant, but if I did, then try messing with `min-height` and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce floats instead of it use display: inline-block; and use media queries for showing it properly on small sized screen

```
#topnav {
    overflow: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
  #menu2{
    background: red;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

checkout this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJeWbd?editors=1100